# What is '>>' when running a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a Move-Mailbox powershell command when I hit enter to run it the prompt changes to >> but nothing else happens. All the parameters have been provided so I don't see that being the cause. It's almost like it's waiting for input but not prompting for what.

```
    [PS] C:\>Move-Mailbox -TargetDatabase "W2K3-LA-EXCH\First Storage Group\MailboxStore" -Identity Toddles -Gl
obalCatalog W2K3.e2k3.exch.com" -SourceForestGlobalCatalog W2K3-LA.e2k7.com -NTAccountOU "OU=Users,DC=e2k3,DC
=exch,DC=com" -SourceForestCredential $SourceCredential -TargetForestCredential $TargetCredential
>>
```

Comment: It happens when your eyes are tired ;-) and it's time to take a break or a sleep!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that case >> is a signal that PowerShell is waiting for you to complete the syntax. In a good case, if you did the following in the interactive console:

```
get-process |
```

You would then get the >> to let you know that the command is incomplete. If I then did:

```
format-table
```

And hit enter a couple times, it would then evaluate.

In your case, it looks like you've got an unpaired quotation mark that is making PowerShell misinterpret it and think you've still got some stuff to add to make it a complete one-liner. Check this parameter, I think you need a starting quote:

```
-GlobalCatalog W2K3.e2k3.exch.com"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was staring at that line for like a half an hour and just couldn't see the missing quote. Once I corrected it, things worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is indicating that the command is not complete. If not deliberate means you have not closed an expression, code block or string.

Answer (score 1):

It means your brackets or quotes are not balanced. In your case, you're missing a double quote:

```
-GlobalCatalog W2K3.e2k3.exch.com"
```

should be:

```
-GlobalCatalog "W2K3.e2k3.exch.com"
```